# Dapper map with prefix in column name

Tags: c#, dapper

I have 2 classes, Order and Address as following:

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

The database stores the orders and address in a single table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
    (
        OrderId NVARCHAR(56) PRIMARY KEY,
        BillingStreet NVARCHAR(256),
        BillingTown NVARCHAR(256),
        BillingZip NVARCHAR(256),
        ShippingStreet NVARCHAR(256),
        ShippingTown NVARCHAR(256),
        ShippingZip NVARCHAR(256)
    )
```

[image]

How can i get dapper to map this to the Order class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do that by making the query generalize the billing and shipping columns and using the version of `Query` that takes multiple types and telling it to split when it sees a column called "Address".  Then you just assign the `Address` objects to the appropriate property on the `Order` object.

```
connection.Query<Order, Address, Address, Order>(
    @"SELECT OrderId, 
             BillingAddress As Address, 
             BillingTown As Town, 
             BillingZip As Zip, 
             ShippingAddress As Address, 
             ShippingTown As Town, 
             ShippingZip As Zip,  
      FROM Orders",
    (o, ba, sa) =>
    {
        o.BillingAddress = ba;
        o.ShippingAddress = sa;
        return o;
    },
    splitOn: "Address");
```

Comment: My database engine requires all aliases to be unique. Does dapper have a way to map Billing* and Shipping* to their respective objects based on a column prefix?

Comment: @Bart You could just handle that in your query like `Select BillingId As Id, BillingName As Name, ShippingId As Id, ShippingName As Name....`  However I believe Dapper does have more complex mapping capabilities, but I've never personally used them.  You might want to write your own question for this.

Comment: Like I said, `BillingId AS Id, ShippingId AS Id` cannot be handled by my database engine because it can't handle non-unique alias names. Anyway, I've solved it in the meantime by using Dapper.SqlMapper, in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with Dapper since it treats row as a single object. It would be possible if you would change your table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderId NVARCHAR(56) PRIMARY KEY,
    BillingAddressId INT
    ShippingAddressId INT
)
```

Then you would have to change your class to:

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ShippingAddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And just use multi mapping.

Another option is to use Dapper extensions like [Dapper-FluentMap](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap) or [Dapper Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) which will help you map columns to classes.